# Erro ao passar dados para tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, realmdb

Opa! galerinha, estou com um problema, estou fazendo um app que consome uma api do themoviedb e salva os filmes no Realm. Na tela principal estou utilizando a CollectionViewController, e ao tocar no filme ele ira para parte de detalhes. Porem quando vai para detalhes nao aparece nada e quando seleciono outro filme ele traz o filme anterior.

Home:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var ListOfMovies: UICollectionView!

//MARK: - Variables
var movies : Results<Moviess>!
let realm = try! Realm()
var detailsMovies = Moviess()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    ListOfMovies.delegate = self
    ListOfMovies.dataSource = self
    searchbar.delegate = self
    movies = realm.objects(Moviess.self)
    getRequest()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

func getObjects(filter: String) -> Results<Moviess>{
    movies = realm.objects(Moviess.self).filter("title CONTAINS[cd] %@",filter)
    return movies
}


func getRequest(){
    print(movies.count)
    if movies.count < 1 {
        RequestData.requisicao { (result) in
               switch(result){
               case .success(let detalhe):
                self.ListOfMovies.reloadData()
               print(detalhe)
               case .failure(let error):
                   print(error)
               }
           }
    }}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return movies.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listOfMovies", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    let infos = movies[indexPath.item]
    cell.configurationMovie(movie: infos)
    return cell
  }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    detailsMovies = movies[indexPath.row]
}


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/2-20, height: 200) : CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/3-20, height: 250)
  }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print(searchText)
    if !searchText.isEmpty{
        let filtro = getObjects(filter: searchText)
        print(filtro)
        ListOfMovies.reloadData()
    }else{
        movies = realm.objects(Moviess.self)
        ListOfMovies.reloadData()
    }
}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if(segue.identifier == "details")
           {
             let viewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            print(detailsMovies)
             viewController.conta = detailsMovies
           }

        }
```

}

Detalhes:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var conta: Moviess!
let realm = try! Realm()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.reloadData()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return [conta].count
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "details", for: indexPath) as! DetailsTableViewCell


    let infos = [conta][indexPath.item]

    cell.prepare(movie: infos!)
    return cell
}
```

}

Não sei onde posso estar errando...

[Q](https://github.com/AndreFirmoo/Test.git)uem quiser dar uma olhada melhor

Comment: Na função `prepare(for segue:, sender: )` , o `print(detailsMovies)` está printando algo? Se não estiver printando, vc verificou se o nome da segue é `"details"` mesmo?

Comment: Cara só uma duvida pra mim poder te ajudar. Você tá usando qual estrutura?